# Debugging HTTP requests: Is there a minimal program which can make GET and POST requests to a webserver?

Tags: http, standards, history

When the standards for the web were first written (one of those being the HTTP standard or specification, which has had several RFC revisions over the past few decades) the first programmers to implement the most basic, low level functionality must have had some kind of tools to debug their webserver implementations.

I would imagine this would be some kind of command line program which was able to make HTTP requests to a specified ip address and print the returned data to standard output or a file.

I imagine such a program would do something like the following...

```
$ httptest 127.0.0.1 GET index.html
Response 200: index.html is
<html>
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

Does such a program exist? (On any OS, but more useful to me personally, for Linux systems.)

One can use a web browser to sort of do this by inspecting the page source, but this doesn't allow the user to make specific requests of each of the possible types defined in the standard.

Comment: Do a web search for "http client linux".

Comment: Clearly off-topic for SO as search for tools/resources... but curl is the answer.

Comment: Not off topic - if I were asking for a debugger (eg gdb) would that be off topic? Clearly not. I am asking for a debugger. Only one which debugs http requests not machine code